node js library to generate a username based on Full Name and current text that user has put in username textfield
Is there a library that does that?
I've tried researching, but most are with only Full Name, but not with Full Name and Pattern (current input in textfield of username). I have a textfield called Username and as user inputs each letter it recommends a username.

Why is this tagged nodejs as it seems it needs to run in the browser? Is this happening in a form text field or some cli?

it is a node.js web socket server front end is flutter

Seems the utility can run on the client and then send the final value through the socket, no? That is to say it isn't strictly node based but rather javascript. Anyway, it doesn't seem all that difficult to create a function that accepts a fullName and pattern and then combines them in some fashion to return a suggested username.
